# heroku create fatal error unable to remap

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, cygwin

On Windows 7 machine, using cygwin ruby 1.92, rails 3.1.3.

I run the heroku create and get the following error message:

```
 heroku create
Creating growing-journey-1774... done, stack is bamboo-mri-1.9.2
http://growing-journey-1774.heroku.com/ | git@heroku.com:growing-journey-1774.git
      1 [main] ruby 4292 C:\cygwin\usr\local\bin\ruby.exe: *** fatal error - unable to remap               \\?\C:\cygwin\usr\local\lib\ruby\1.9.1\i386-cygwin\etc.so to same address as parent: 0x3E0000               != 0x3F0000
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
0028A778  6102796B  (0028A778, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000)
0028AA68  6102796B  (6117EC60, 00008000, 00000000, 61180977)
0028BA98  61004F1B  (611A7FAC, 61248A3C, 003E0000, 003F0000)
End of stack trace
      1 [main] ruby 2856 fork: child 4292 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
1086458 [main] ruby 2944 C:\cygwin\usr\local\bin\ruby.exe: *** fatal error - unable to remap               \\?\C:\cygwin\usr\local\lib\ruby\1.9.1\i386-cygwin\etc.so to same address as parent: 0x3E0000               != 0x410000
Stack trace:
Frame     Function  Args
0028A778  6102796B  (0028A778, 00000000, 00000000, 00000000)
0028AA68  6102796B  (6117EC60, 00008000, 00000000, 61180977)
0028BA98  61004F1B  (611A7FAC, 61248A3C, 003E0000, 00410000)
End of stack trace
1098573 [main] ruby 2856 fork: child 2944 - died waiting for dll loading, errno 11
```

I was able to upload the SSH keys to heroku just fine in the previous step.

Any ideas? My research hasn't led me anywhere. Appreciate anybody's help!

My Gem env shows:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.12
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.2 (2011-07-09 patchlevel 290) [i386-cygwin]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/ruby.exe
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86-cygwin
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1
     - /home/Philip/.gem/ruby/1.9.1
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :benchmark => false
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - http://rubygems.org/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem looks like more with Ruby or Cygwin setup and less with Heroku, try following link solution
http://redmine.jamoma.org/projects/jamoma/wiki/Setting_up_development_environment_in_Windows

Comment: tried running ash.exe and followed instructions, typed ./rebaseall and came back with "usr/bin/tclpip84.dll: skipped because not rebaseable"

Comment: I am not quite sure of Cygwin error, you should google it and fix Cygwin errors first.

Comment: got it, thanks. I didnt realize at first this is a cygwin error

Comment: had to rebase, restart computer and finally got it working. thx!